# Count month different from to date SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have a problem in counting month's difference from 2 date with sql server query

i tried using `DATEDIFF(MONTH, SD, ED)`

this for example

```
SD = '2013-12-10 00:00:00.000'
ED = '2014-12-09 00:00:00.000'
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, SD, ED)

--result : 12 //this correct result


SD = '2013-12-10 00:00:00.000'
ED = '2014-12-10 00:00:00.000'
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, SD, ED)

--result : 12 //this incorrect result, the result that i want is 13


SD = '2013-12-10 00:00:00.000'
ED = '2014-12-15 00:00:00.000'
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, SD, ED)

--result : 12 //this incorrect result, the result that i want is 13

SD = '2013-12-01 00:00:00.000'
ED = '2014-11-30 00:00:00.000'
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, SD, ED)

--result : 11//this incorrect result, the result that i want is 12
```

is there any solution to get correct result of month difference of 2 date??
can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Define your vision of the "*correct result*" for any two given dates.

Comment: Datediff looks like the wrong solution, although if you add a month to ED and then subtract  a day  (or possibly the other way round) it might work.  You might get better answers if you describe what you want to count. the examples are confusing and not precise enough to give an exact answer.

Answer (score 5):

`DATEDIFF` only compares the months regardless of the dates within. As you're wanting to include part-months, try comparing the dates as well, and adding `CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,@d2) >= DATEPART(day,@d1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

So to use the notation from your question:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, SD, ED) +
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, ED) >= DATEPART(DAY, SD) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: The same thing I specified in my edit but he gave some other example and said its giving Incorrect result

Answer (score 2):

`DATEDIFF()` works differently than many people expect. From the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified *datepart* boundaries crossed between the specified *startdate* and *enddate*.

`DATEDIFF(MONTH, @startdate, @enddate)` is equivalent to

```
(YEAR(@enddate) - YEAR(@startdate)) * 12 + (MONTH(@enddate) - MONTH(@startdate)).
```

So for `2013-12-01` and `2014-11-30`, its `(2014-2013) * 12 + (11 - 12)`

which is indeed 11.  For `'2013-12-31'` and `'2014-11-01'` it is also 11.  Again, it's done this way because it's the only culture-neutral and fully consistent way to do it.

You will need to define what "correct" is in terms of your application and then write your query as such.  If you need to use the logic repeatedly, a user-defined function is recommended.

Comment: @RobFarley No, it's stupid.  As in lacking any intelligence for understanding what the user wants, and in my experience what a user *actually* wants is *never* what `DATEDIFF()` actually does, yet it's the only default function that does this operation.  Thus: *It's always non-intuitive*.  It works so for good reason (a function that does what all users want would be too complex), but that makes it very limited (or, as I said: stupid).  It's not prefabricated structure.  It's just a tool you can use to build one yourself.  That's actually kind of unusual in SQL.